# Read Word in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I have **input** as

```
string afterIN = "Text Field= Assignee AND Ticket Status != Deleted";
```

And I try *processing* it with my code below:

```
char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };

string text = afterIN;

string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
string str = "";

foreach (var word in words)
{
    if (word != "")
    {
        string strDelimit = "\"";

        str += strDelimit + word + strDelimit + ",";
    }
}
```

I want **output** as

```
"Text Field",
"=",
"Assignee",
"AND",
"Ticket Status",
"!=",
"Deleted"
```

Another type of **input** is SQL query, e.g.

```
SELECT # Tickets WHERE Ticket Status=Open OR Ticket Status=Pending
```

Desired **output** is splitted `WHERE`:

```
"Ticket Status",
"=",
"Open",
"OR",
"Ticket Status",
"=",
"Pending"
```

Comment: You need to first lay out your rules on a piece of paper before you can program them. We don't know, why you expect that output. Why would it parse your string that way? Obviously it's not just splitting at certain characters. Can you write a grammar for it?

Comment: You cannot have "Text Field" if you define " " to be a delimiter. What you want seems to be more complex than you think.

Comment: I  am creating dynamic string to be passed as in put to a tool . like this IF  [Text Field - Unsorted]="Assignee"  AND  [Ticket Status  - Unsorted]!="Deleted"  THEN [Update ID] ENDIF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *general case* you want a *parser*; however, if there's a guarantee that the source string
doesn't have *comments*, *strings* and other complex syntax constructions e.g.

```
  // here we should split on first 2 "AND"s
  Text Filed = /* And is commented*/ "A \"AND B" /* String */ AND Ticket Status != Deleted
```

You can try splitting with a help of *regular expressions*:

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string source = "Text Field = Assignee AND Ticket Status != Deleted";

  // split on =, !=, and, or
  // Trim() each item if you want to get rid of leading / trailing spaces 
  string[] items = Regex.Split(
      source, 
    @"(!=|\band\b|=|\bor\b)", 
      RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

For processing a (very) **simple** SQL (no comments, strings etc.) we can add some *Linq* (to `Skip` initial part of the query and `Take` only `where` part):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
... 
string source = 
  @"SELECT # Tickets 
     WHERE Ticket Status <> Open OR Ticket Status > Pending 
  GROUP BY x 
  ORDER BY y";

string[] delimiters = new string[] {
  "where",
  "order",
  "group",

  //TODO: put all delimiters here
  ">", "<", "<>", "=", "!=", ">=", "<=",
  "and", "or", "not"
};

string pattern = string.Join("|", delimiters
  .OrderByDescending(item => item.Length)
  .Select(item => item.All(c => char.IsLetter(c)) 
      ? $@"\b{item}\b" 
      : Regex.Escape(item))); 

string[] items = Regex
  .Split(source, $"({pattern})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
  .Select(item => item.Trim())
  .SkipWhile(item => !"where".Equals(item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  .Skip(1) 
  .TakeWhile(item => !"order".Equals(item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                     !"group".Equals(item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: it is working . But if group by and order by is there input will it work?

Comment: @user1994518: in *general case* you have to *parse* the sql; however, you can slightly improve the code in order to support `group by` as well as `order by`. I've edited the answer

Comment: Text Field= Assignee AND Ticket Status <> Deleted . Can i read word before = or <> or !=  can you Take While ?how to write

Comment: @user1994518: you have to mention all delimiters (`<>`) in order to have a desired *pattern*, I've extracted delimiters as an array for easier work